# Get Posts on index page

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

**I'm trying to get posts on Index page using laravel but getting errors.**

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    return view('pages.index')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

The above snippet defines what I want to do, but, getting this error on index page:

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

Same snippet works on other pages but it's not working on index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the results using get method like so:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```